# What is the best practice for a Circuit Breaker, catch all Exceptions or specific ones?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, exception, circuit-breaker

So I'm using [Polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly) (fantastic) for a circuit breaker in C#.

I was using it to just catch a handful of exceptions when calling a web service, for example:

```
    _policy = Policy
        .Handle<TargetInvocationException>()
        .Or<CommunicationException>()
        .Or<EndpointNotFoundException>()
...
```

But I'm wondering if it would be far easier to just do:

```
   _policy = Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()
```

Then in the case of the service call having any issues of any kind I am covered.
However I'm worried now that by doing this I'll cause myself issues in future that I haven't considered.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have no idea if there are specific needs for this for Circuit breakers, but in general this is a bad idea, at the very worst, it can mean that an error will appear later on that would never of happened as your initial error would have caught it - as well as provided a clearer reasoning behind the failure

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm a bit late to the party but I just put together a library for just this situation and to allow for the circuit to run over different threads such as requests from a web server:

https://github.com/InvitationDigital/IDL.Net.CircuitBreaker

This allows you to catch your exceptions and only get circuit breaker errors when the circuit is open.